# Visual Studio 2013 fails to load XAML correctly

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I am testing VS 2013 and have a rather strange bug: I am loading a XAML file which usese a namespace to implement a Valueconverter. This WORKS finde when running, but in the development view I am getting an error, which states that the Converter is not found.
I tried to clean the solution, deleted the .user and .suo files, but to no avail

Code looks like this:

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="bla.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"  
        xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:bla.Utils"
        Title="bla" Width="1024" Height="768" Icon="/bla;component/Images/Table.ico" MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300">

    <RibbonWindow.Resources>
        <Converter:SpssVarTypeConverter x:Key="SpssVarTypeConverter"></Converter:SpssVarTypeConverter>
    </RibbonWindow.Resources>
</RibbonWindow>
```

And the converter:

```
using bla.SPSS;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace bla.Utils
{
    public class SpssVarTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var type = (Types)value;

            if (type == Types.numerisch)
            { 
                return Brushes.LightBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                return Brushes.PaleVioletRed;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they have some problems with their IDE.
I got a similar message in Visual Basic when I tried to use the Left(T,2) string function.
It throws the error 'not implemented" because it conflicts with the control property 'Left.
Then it inserts the prototype for a new function for Left String at the end of the code.

```
Private Function Left(DB As String, p2 As Integer) As String
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```

It is a fine example of Microsoft's massive failure to test their products before they release them.